# JpaRepository Interface - No property owner found

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I got a strange error even though I think everything looks OK.

Pet class:

```
@Entity
public class Pet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    ....
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private PetOwner petOwner;
}
```

PetOwner

```
@Entity(name = "pet_owner")
public class PetOwner extends User{
     ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "petOwner")
    private List<Pet> pets;
}
```

Pet Repository

```
@Repository
public interface PetRepository extends JpaRepository<Pet, Long> {
    List<Pet> findByOwner(PetOwner owner);
}
```

As you can see i want to get a list of animals giving the owner. During application running get the error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'petRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property owner found for type Pet!

Why get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you named your field as `petOwner`, you should use `findByPetOwner` method name instead of `findByOwner`:

```
@Repository
public interface PetRepository extends JpaRepository<Pet, Long> {
    List<Pet> findByPetOwner(PetOwner owner);
}
```

Spring Data JPA attempts to construct a store-specific query from *the query method name*. The general approach is to remove a given set of well-known prefixes (e.g. `find...By` or `get...By`) from the method name and parse the rest of the method using `Property Expressions` (e.g. `petOnwer`, in your case) and set of `Clauses` like `Top`, `Distinct`, `OrderBy`. Those Property expressions can refer only to a **direct property of the managed entity**. In your case since your property name is `petOwner`, you can not use `owner` or anything besides the `petOwner`. You can read more about this concept [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation).

Comment: Ok. It's working. Could you now explain why ? 
I thought that this is the name of the method and does not depend on the name of Bean

Comment: Thanks. I understand